# Adobe Reader not accessing Symbolic Link over network drive

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, symbolic-link, adobe-reader, network-drive

My main system is running Windows 7.  I have a mapped network drive (call it z:) that is hosted on a Windows XP machine (not sure if this matters at all).  I have created a Symbolic link (call it SL, located on my main system's desktop) to one of the directories (call it Docs) in the mapped netword drive that contains a number of *.pdf, *.xls and *.doc files.  The symbolic link directory is browsable in explorer and all of the MicroSoft Office files work perfectly through the symbolic link.  However, when I try to open any of the *.pdf files, I get an error in Adobe Reader (Reader opens, but cannot access the file).  Next I created (I don't know what possessed me to try this) a shortcut (call it SC, also on my desktop) that points to SL.  The chain looks like this:

SC --> SL --> z:/Docs

The shortcut SC is also browsable in explorer, all of the Office files respond correctly through SC, but now, so do the *.pdf files; Reader has no problem opening and displaying any of them when opened through SC.  What is missing so that I can access the *.pdf files directly through the SL?

Comment: I ended up installing Sumatra PDF as my PDF viewer. Since my complete profile directory was symlinked Adobe Reader wouldn't open anything.